# Implement pattern match on FindUsersByName

Tags: c#, asp.net-membership, pattern-matching

I would like some feedback on the code below. And how would I Implement pattern matching on FindUsersByName in role so that an exact match for username is not required?

```
// MembershipProvider.FindUsersByName       
public override MembershipUserCollection FindUsersByName(string usernameToMatch, int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalRecords)
{
  MembershipUserCollection users = new MembershipUserCollection();

  try
  {
    Profile.MembershipMapper memberMapper = new MembershipMapper();
    List<Profile.Membership> recs = (List<Profile.Membership>)memberMapper.GetMembershipsByUsername(_memberUtil.GetApplicationId(), usernameToMatch, pageIndex, pageSize, out totalRecords);

    foreach (Profile.Membership rec in recs)
    {
      users.Add(GetUserFromModel(rec, usernameToMatch));
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Exception e = CheckEventLog(ex, "FindUsersByName");
    throw e;
  }

  return users;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want fuzzy matching you could use a regular expression.  Have the input pass in a RegEx string.  You haven't been very clear on what should match and what shouldn't.

Comment: Im trying to match the user names in a role. for example, testuser should match TestUser1